# Adding a prefix to Zend Framework's validation messages

Tags: php, validation, zend-framework, zend-form

I need to add a prefix to error messages which are displayed when the validation on the Zend_From fails.

Right now I am setting custom messages on the validators which I need. As shown in the example below.

```
$element->addValidator('NotEmpty', true, array('messages' => '<span class="glyphicons glyphicons-up_arrow errMsgIcon"></span> Username can\'t be left blank'))
```

But is there a way to add the prefix defined below on all validation messages which are triggered?

```
<span class="glyphicons glyphicons-up_arrow errMsgIcon"></span>
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: From what I remember, error messages are rendered in a HTML list by default. Are you not able to style that, rather than trying to add HTML to the message itself?

Comment: I am using bootstrap and according to that certain styles require tags like <span> to be added to the element. I can define my own css classes and can try to change this behavior.Thanks for help..